# Git Mergetool Error (Unexpected character b at line 1) and Hangs

Tags: xcode, git-merge

After local commit, I pull on a branch, received with conflicts, I run the mergetool. After done the first merging with opendiff, the terminal simply hangs with the following error message:

> FileMerge[1216:43748] Couldn't load
>   '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Specifications/Core
>   Build System.xcspec'. Reason: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=3840 "Unexpected character b at line 1"
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unexpected character b at line 1,
>   kCFPropertyListOldStyleParsingError=Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=3840 "Unexpected ';' or '=' after key at line 1"
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unexpected ';' or '=' after key at line
>   1}}. 2017-03-31 11:32:22.402 FileMerge[1216:43748] Couldn't load
>   '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Specifications/Native
>   Build System.xcspec'. Reason: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=3840 "Unexpected character b at line 1"
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unexpected character b at line 1,
>   kCFPropertyListOldStyleParsingError=Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=3840 "Unexpected ';' or '=' after key at line 1"
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unexpected ';' or '=' after key at line
>   1}}.

Had no choice to open the project and manually inspect each conflicts. O_O

Anybody know what is the issue and how to fix it? Running XCode 8.2.1. On a native iOS project with cocoapods installed.